# TCP Session drops because of FIN signal

Tags: linux, cisco-asa, tcpip, site-to-site-vpn, juniper

I have two servers communicating with each other through ISO 8385 messages over TCP sessions. Basically host-to-host interface between two payment switches. The problem is that the session keeps dropping and when we investigated the reason (TCP dump), we found that the client-server sends a FIN message after each new transaction. We are not sure where this FIN signal is coming from, and we are confident that it is not coming from the application itself. So my question is, is it possible that network configuration is what causes this signal to be sent? Note: the two servers are connected by site-to-site VPN connection and we are using ASA firewall on both ends

Note: both servers are Linux

Comment: `We are not sure where this FIN signal is coming from`. Did the packet capture on the client show a FIN?

Comment: Yes it did, I have the logs

Comment: Looks like an application bug rather than a network bug.